# How to Parse an XML (using XELement) having multiple Namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing

I get the followinng Xresponse after parsing the XML document:

```
 <DIDL-Lite 
xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" 
       xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
       xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/" 
       xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:metadata-1-0/">
<item id="1182" parentID="40" restricted="1"> 
<title>Hot Issue</title> 
</item>
```

As per the earlier thread, When there is a default namespace in the document, you must parse it as if it were a named namespace. For example.

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/"; 

var xDIDL = xResponse.Element(ns + "DIDL-Lite");
```

But in my case I have four different name space. I am not getting any results after using the following query , I am getting the response , Not Yeilding any results:

```
   XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
     var vAudioData = from xAudioinfo in xResponse.Descendants(ns + "DIDL-lite").Elements("item")
                                                                                             select new RMSMedia
                                                     {
         strAudioTitle = ((string)xAudioinfo.Element(dc + "title")).Trim(),
};
```

I have no clue whats going on as am new to it. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `item` element is in your "ns" namespace. Use:-

```
XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
XName didl = ns + "DIDL-lite";
XName item = ns + "item";
XName title = dc + "title";

var vAudioData = from xAudioinfo in xResponse.Descendants(didl).Elements(item)

select new RMSMedia
{
     strAudioTitle = ((string)xAudioinfo.Element(title)).Trim(),
};
```

In these cases I tend to create myself a private class to hold the set of XNames I need to simplify the query code.

Comment: Thanks a Ton Obaliz and Anthony for your expert suggestion. Itz working now

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting any results because you are using the wrong namespace. All elements without prefix are in the namespace `urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/`.

Items in the namespace `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/` are prefixed with `dc:` in the xml document. The fragment does not show any items so it is hart to tell what elements you are looking for.

For example - given the following xml:

```
<DIDL-Lite 
xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" 
       xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
       xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/" 
       xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:metadata-1-0/">
<item id="1182" parentID="40" restricted="1"> 
<title>Hot Issue</title> 
<dc:title>Purl Title</dc:title>
</item> 
</DIDL-Lite>
```

And also given the assumption that you want to retrieve both titles the following code should yiedl the results you are looking for:

```
XNamespace dc= "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/";

var result = xAudioinfo.Descendants(ns + "title"); // <title></title>
var result2 = xAudioinfo.Descendants(dc + "title"); // <dc:title></dc:title>
```